# How can use history.go(-1) but ignore hash fragments?

Tags: javascript

I have the following links:

```
index.php
test.php
test.php#tab1
test.php#tab2
```

On the `test.php` page I click on link `#tab1`, and then `#tab2`. I want clicking on the back link:

```
<a href="javascript: history.go(-1);" title="Back">« Back</a>
```

...to go back to `index.php`.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Use [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/), if there is a hash skip, in other case add the link with pushState.

Answer (score 0):

since you have PHP pages, why are you seeking a JS solution?

Why not use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` in your PHP?

Comment: HTTP_REFERER remembers only 1 previous page.

Answer (score 0):

javascript: history.go(-1); in JavaScript use internal history of browser. So, when you call history.back() browser open previous page from history. The tabs that you use on test.php page are on the one page and browser means that it's one page. I think, that you mast use direct link like Back